# hiding the checkbox of checkedtextview

Tags: android

i m using checkedtextview in listview.i want to display olly the textview when d list view is first loaded.when i click on a button i want to populate the list view with different data and which should show the checkbox also.(i m not able to hide the checkbox of checked textview initially).plz help me

Answer (score 6):

I would simply use a custom adapter that will return either a TextView or a CheckedTextView depending on whether you have clicked your button.

Also you could try to do `checkedTextView.setCheckMarkDrawable(null);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<CheckedTextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
android:checkMark="@null"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but this might help someone in the future

Step 1

create a `boolean` variable in onCreate to ease the `if|else|while` method (will use in step 3)

```
 boolean changedData = true;
```

Step 2

> i want to display olly the textview when d list view is first loaded

Just leave your code as it is, assuming it looks like this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter
                        = new ArrayAdapter<String>(yourActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        yourData);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Step 3

> when i click on a button i want to populate the list view with different data and which should show the checkbox also

just create a new button like so

```
 populateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (changedData == true) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter 
                                    = new ArrayAdapter<String>(yourActivity.this,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                                    differentData);
           listView.setAdapter(adapter);
           changedData = false;
        }else if (changedData == false) {
                 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter 
                                    = new ArrayAdapter<String>(yourActivity.this,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                    yourData);
           listView.setAdapter(adapter);
           changedData = true;
        }
   });
}
```

This way, the first time you click your button you will get a `ListView` with `CheckBox` with your new data

And upon clicking the button again it will go back to the `ListView` with no `CheckBox` with your old data

If you want to make the `CheckBox` checkable, just read the answer from this link

[Simple list item multiple choice not selecting items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190430/simple-list-item-multiple-choice-not-selecting-items)