# Simple list item multiple choice not selecting items

Tags: android, list

I've created an array list and display it in a list view with simple list item multiple choice but i cannot check or tick the items on the list, when i click on the items nothing happens. Please check my code below and tell me what i am doing wrong.

```
package com.example.arrays;

import java.util.Random;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView showList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView show = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtShow);
    final Random generate = new Random();
    showList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    final String[] myAttraction = new String[4];
    myAttraction[0]= "Walter Sisulu National Botanical Garden ";
    myAttraction[1]= "Coca-Cola Dome";
    myAttraction[2]= "Promusica Theatre";
    myAttraction[3]= "Unisa Science Campus";
    Button arrays = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    arrays.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            /*int random = generate.nextInt(4);
            String display = myAttraction[random];
            show.setText(display);*/

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, myAttraction);
            showList.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    });
    showList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "long clicked pos: " + pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

Comment: You are using `setOnItemLongClickListener`, which is expecting a *long* click, is it what do you want?

Comment: no i want when the user clicks the item must be selected not a long click.

Comment: Then you should use `showList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { ... ` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but still doesn't work, i've removed all onclick listeners and left only the arrayAdapater and listview still not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a `OnItemClickListener` like this to check/uncheck the `CheckedTextView` when user click on an item

```
showList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // change the checkbox state
            CheckedTextView checkedTextView = ((CheckedTextView)view);
            checkedTextView.setChecked(!checkedTextView.isChecked());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, how can i display the checkboxes on the left.

Comment: You need to create a custom layout with a checkbox and TextView

Answer (score 0):

change your code as following....

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, myAttraction);
            showList.setAdapter(adapter);

 arrays.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            /*int random = generate.nextInt(4);
            String display = myAttraction[random];
            show.setText(display);*/
        }
    });

 showList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "long clicked pos: " + pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `choiceMode` property of your list to `multipleChoice`. I'm implementing multiple choice list in such a way in my applications, and it surely works.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, myAttraction);
  showList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To this

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, myAttraction);
  showList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
  showList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Just Add this line if you have a ListView and have selected `simple_list_item_multiple_choice` and you are unable to interact with the checkbox.

```
YourListViewName.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```